# Insert Parametrised value within a LIKE statement

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mono

I have a method that updates a record in a mysql database, and the query works perfectly well when simply using when the string as follows:

```
string query = @"UPDATE Batches SET `State`=@State, `PostDocCount`=@PostDocCount WHERE `FilePath` LIKE '%MYDIRECTORYSTRING%'";
```

Although if I replace MYDIRECTORYSTRING with a parameterized query e.g:

```
string query = @"UPDATE Batches SET `State`=@State, `PostDocCount`=@PostDocCount WHERE `FilePath` LIKE '%@dirName%'";
```

it no longer works (record is not updated) - I have also confirmed that @dirName == MYDIRECTORYSTRING as well. So I am led to believe this is a syntax problem? (Although both queries do appear to execute ok..)

Below is my full method:

```
 public void UpdateBatch(string postDocCount, string dirName, string state)
        {
        string query = @"UPDATE Batches SET `State`=@State, `PostDocCount`=@PostDocCount WHERE `FilePath` LIKE '%@dirName%'";

        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //create mysql command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            //Assign the query using CommandText
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            //Assign the connection using Connection
            cmd.Connection = connection;

            // Parametized queries 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostDocCount", postDocCount);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", state);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dirName", dirName);

            //Execute query
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before assigning the `dirName` variable to the `"@dirName"` parameter you should incorporate the % wild cards

```
dirName = "%" + dirName + "%";
```

and then change your sql text to

```
string query = @"UPDATE Batches SET `State`=@State, `PostDocCount`=@PostDocCount " + 
                "WHERE `FilePath` LIKE @dirName";
```

Comment: Meaning? It doesn't work because... ? Did you step through your code with the debugger and do you get errors or just the update doesn't happen? In the latter case, did you check if the variable used as dirName contains a valid search value?